# What algorithm should I use for the following sequential dataset training?

Tags: security, nlp, dataset, lstm, word2vec

I have a dataset that contains opcode sequences of malware files. I read a paper where the author tried to implement a RNN algorithm like LSTM, but he specified a preprocessing step where he creates a word-bag and uses Word2Vec to convert everything into vectorized format.
I am stuck at this place. Any help would be appreciated.

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec()
model.build_vocab(sequence_text, progress_per=1000)
model.train(sequence_text, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.epochs)
```

I will also put a screenshot of the CSV file.
[image: Dataset]

Ultimate Goal: I need to identify if a sequence belongs to malware class or not.

Comment: To have any chance, you'll also need negative-examples of non-malware - which aren't shown in your example data. (And, if they're just 'later', note that leaving all alike-examples contiguous in the training data usually hurts training.) But also: I doubt a simple shallow word2vec model on individual opcodes will be very helpful here. You'll likely need to extract other longer-range features – sets/patterns of opcodes in runs or nearby – either via your own heuristics or some deeper sequence-analyzing neural network.

Comment: Thank you, I don't have any negative samples as of now, but am trying to obtain them. I don't have time and resources to extract new features or sets/patterns. What do you think is the best way (algorithm preferably) to achieve my goal under these circumstances? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know offhand any standard/reliable way to learn malware patterns – an especially difficult problem because it doesn't want to be detected. So I'd search research papers for anything that's been tried & shown to have promising results. (And again, I doubt a simple per-opcode model will help much - the combinations, & net effects, of many opcodes would seem the best signal of malicious intent.)